# NgRx8 destruct values from action

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

everyone, I would like to destruct action type and props in ngrx effect, I'm in a stuck with how I can do it

My actions:

```
export const addTab = createAction(
  '[SuperUserTabs] add tab',
  props<{ tab: SuperUserHeaderTab, tabType: TabType }>()
);

export const searchCompanyTab = createAction(
  '[SuperUserTabs] search company tab'
);

export const searchCardholderTab = createAction(
  '[SuperUserTabs] search cardholder tab'
);
```

Effect:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  addTab$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(
      TabsActions.addTab,
      TabsActions.searchCompanyTab,
      TabsActions.searchCardholderTab
    ),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getTabs))),
    tap(([action, tabs]) => {
      // destruct here 
      const {type, props} = action;
      // some logic
    })
  );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean fire a `destruct` action or 'destroy an action' (whatever that means) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**: `ofType` accept action creator, so you can using it directly:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  addTab$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(
      TabsActions.addTab,
      TabsActions.searchCompanyTab,
      TabsActions.searchCardholderTab
    ),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getTabs))),
    tap(([action, tabs]) => {
      // this object will contain `type` and action payload
      const {type, ...payload} = action; 
      // some logic
      console.log(payload)
    })
  );
```

==============
**Old answer also work:**

because you're using action creator, which return a function, so you can access action type through `type` property like this:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  addTab$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(
      TabsActions.addTab.type,
      TabsActions.searchCompanyTab.type,
      TabsActions.searchCardholderTab.type
    ),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getTabs))),
    tap(([action, tabs]) => {
      // this object will contain `type` and action payload
      const {type, ...payload} = action; 
      // some logic
      console.log(payload)
    })
  );
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3t2fmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore.ts